# Converting A Columnless Matrix To dict

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dictionary

I want to fetch data from a text file that doesn't have columns, but has about 8 entries, and I want to give each column a name as shown in this code, but I want an alternative because it's running very slow. I want an easier solution than this, thank you

Programming language:Python

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv("drive/MyDrive/Test.TxT", header=None)

#Convert Data
def ConvTDi(lst):
  if type(lst) is dict:
    return lst
  else:
    return {'Col1': lst[0], 'Col2': lst[1], 'Col3': lst[2], 'Col4': lst[3], 'Col5': lst[4], 'Col6': lst[5], 'Col7': lst[6], 'Col8': lst[7]}

def RetCTDV():
  ValC = ConvTDi(dataframe.iloc[0,0:8].values)
  for i in range(len(dataframe.index)):
    if i == 0:
      i = 1
    ValC = np.append(ValC, ConvTDi(dataframe.iloc[i,0:8].values))
  return ValC

input_data = RetCTDV()
output_data = dataframe.iloc[:,8].values
```

Values Data:

```
2106040200,275020300,243020300,2640102010,21180204020,156050100,286040200,1640102010,0
275020300,243020300,2640102010,21180204020,156050100,286040200,1640102010,156040200,1 30 130
143040200,2640102010,21180204020,156050100,286040200,1640102010,156040200,2960102030,1 0 160
2640102010,21180204020,156050100,286040200,1640102010,156040200,2960102030,254020200,1 10 150
21180204020,156050100,286040200,1640102010,156040200,2960102030,254020200,2640102010,0
156050100,286040200,1640102010,156040200,2960102030,254020200,2640102010,11080203030,0
286040200,1640102010,156040200,2960102030,254020200,2640102010,11080203030,1117020050,0
```

I want to come up with this example for each row:

```
{Col1:275020300,Col2:243020300,Col3:2640102010,Col4:21180204020,Col5:156050100,Col6:286040200,Col7:1640102010,Col8:156040200},1 30 130
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Add code as text, not as image. Also, add more details like the programming language that you are using and any other relevant detail so other might reproduce the problem. Ref. [mcve].

Comment: Edit and add the problem code. Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the data into a dataframe, convert the first eight columns to dictionaries, append the last column:

```
x = pd.read_table("Test.TxT", header=None, sep=',', 
       names=["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5","Col6","Col7","Col8",""])

pd.concat([x.iloc[:,:-1].apply(dict), x.iloc[:,-1]], axis=1)
```